# VSCode - Import suggestions for JavaScript don't work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Any ideas why Import intellisense/suggestions wouldn't work in a JS project? Here's the [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "esnext",
        "baseUrl": "./src/",
        "paths": {
            "@src/*": ["*"],
            "@core/*": ["core/*"]
        },
        "esModuleInterop": false
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

It is a node project, that has path aliasing achieved with the "module-alias" NPM package. Here are the aliases in package.json:

```
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@src": "./src",
    "@core": "./src/core"
  }
```

Code works fine during runtime, but VSCode doesn't offer any import suggestions. If I have an undefined function in script A.js, it doesn't offer to import it from script A.js.
I got it to help with imports by setting `checkJs` to `true` in jsconfig.json, but even then it auto-generated the imports using the new import/export syntax, even though I need them imported in the CommonJS format.

Here's another issue that VSCode has that could be related. It shows an error in jsconfig.json that seems completely unrelated to it. The error itself is pretty strange as well.

[image]